# code to generate beep sound in Blackberry 8520

Tags: blackberry

I have developed an application for blackberry 8520 version 5.0 in Blackberry Eclipse. Now I want to generate a beep sound when I start that application in Blackberry Mobile. I used `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();` to generate the beep sound, but it is not working.

Could anyone please help me with the code for generating a beep sound?

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: its showing some error . asking me to create Toolkit class.

Comment: if possible could you please help me with the code to generate Beep sound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare this at start point:

```
short frequency = 1046;
short duration = 200;
int volume = 100;
```

then call this method where you want the Beep sound:

```
public void beepSound() 
{
    UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run() 
        {                
            Alert.startAudio(new short[]{frequency, duration}, volume);                 
        }
    });
}
```

Try this one;

Comment: Am testing this in simulator . can i hear the beep sound when i test in  simulator

Comment: yes. you can hear the beep in any device; if you are testing in simulator open the volume in the computer monitor and see the volume when click on beep;

Answer (score 0):

To make the BlackBerry make a simple beep sound use the following method:

```
public void beepSound() {

    short frequency = 1046;
    short duration = 200;
    int volume = 100;   
    Alert.startAudio(new short[]{frequency, duration}, volume);                         
}
```

Note: All credit to alishaik786 for their original answer, this just removes the redundant wrapping in the UI thread since `Alert.startAudio` does not block.